# Set default data on Symfony text field with data transformer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am working on a project to dynamically create Symfony forms on the fly using a yaml file (or any other data source that may return form description as an associative array). To handle things better I want to wrap Symfony's core types to work with a data object instead of scalar data. The data object will be a simple wrapper with getter-setter.

```
class SimpleFormData implements FormData {

    /**
     * @var mixed data
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $data
     */
    public function setData($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

I started with writing a data transformer:

```
class SimpleFormDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {
    /**
     * @param mixed $value The value in the original representation
     * @return mixed The value in the transformed representation
     * @throws TransformationFailedException When the transformation fails.
     */
    public function transform($value) {
        if(is_null($value)) {
            return '';
        }

        if($value instanceof FormData) {
            return $value->getData();
        }

        $actualType = is_object($value) ? 'an instance of class '.get_class($value) : ' a(n) '.gettype($value);

        $message = sprintf("Expected argument of type MyApp\\FormBundle\\FormData\\FormData, got %s", $actualType);
        throw new TransformationFailedException($message);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $value The value in the transformed representation
     * @return mixed The value in the original representation
     * @throws TransformationFailedException When the transformation fails.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value) {
        return new SimpleFormData($value);
    }
}
```

I created a custom TextType and set model transformer to it:

```
class TextType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $transformer = new SimpleFormDataTransformer();
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'form_bundle_type_core_text';
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'text';
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if I create a TextType and set data by calling setData method:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TextType());
$form->setData(new SimpleFormData("test"));
```

If I try passing default data, I get an error:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TextType(), new SimpleFormData("test"));
```

The error thrown says:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   MyApp\FormBundle\Model\SimpleFormData, but is a(n) string. You can
>   avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by
>   adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance
>   of MyApp\FormBundle\Model\SimpleFormData.

I certainly don't want viewData to be of type SimpleFormData (hence the transformer). Also, I haven't set data_class, Symfony's Form class picks data class from the passed data object.

I have two questions:

1. What should I do to be able to pass default data?
2. Why Symfony expects viewData to be of type data_class? My understanding was that modelData should be of type data_class and not viewData.

Comment: You may be able to handle your use case with a PRE_SET form event listener instead of the model transformer. You can then pass the name of your config 'identifier' via an option?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I don't think this will help my use case. Agreed, that I can probably accept a SimpleFormData object and then update the value in event using getData() on my SimpleFormData object. But, still ModelData on my field will be scalar i.e. if I do a getData() on my field, it would return me a scalar string value instead of a SimpleFormData object. Please correct me if I am wrong.